# Where are these infrastructure entries coming from in AWS SAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm learning SAM, and I created two projects.

The first one, example1, I created it from the AWS web console, by going to Lambda, Applications, and choosing this template:

[image]

After the wizard finishes creating the app, it looks like this:

[image]

I'm interested in the yellow-highlighted area because I don't understand it yet.

I tried to replicate this more or less manually by using `sam init` and created example2. It's easy to look at the `template.yml` it creates and see how the stuff in Resources are created, but how is the stuff in  Infrastructure created.

When I deploy example2 with `sam deploy --guided`, indeed there's nothing in Infrastructure:

[image]

Given example2, how should I go about creating the same infrastructure as example1 had out of the box (and then changing it, for example, I want several environments, prod, staging, etc). Is this point and click in the AWS console or can it be done with CloudFormation?

I tried adding a permission boundary to example2, on of the things example1 has in Infrastructure, I created the policy in IAM (manually, in the console), added it to the `template.yml`, and deployed it but it didn't show up in "Infrastructure".

Comment: How/what are you deploying in the console?

Comment: @Paolo: I just created the example, I didn't do any deployment. But if I push changes to that repo, it deploys automatically.

Comment: Which example? It's not clear how the second deployment is taking place

Comment: @Paolo: I re-wrote the question to make it more clear.

Comment: That's much clearer, thanks

Comment: I just tested out a simple SAM deployment with a lambda and a role; while I would assume that the role would fall under the "infrastructure" section, it seems it doesn't. From what I can tell, it seems like this split is happening behind the scenes and it isn't something that the user can configure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Part 1: In which I answer your question

> Where are these infrastructure entries coming from in AWS SAM?

I replicated your steps in the Lambda console to create a "Serverless API Backend" called `super-app`.  When you press `create`, AWS creates
two [CloudFormation Stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/stacks.html), each with a YAML template.  You can view the stack resources and the YAML templates in the CloudFormation console under `Stacks > Templates Tab`.

1. `super-app`: the "Resources" stack with the lambda and dynamo resources you managed to replicate.
2. `serverlessrepo-super-app-toolchain`: the mystery stack with the "Infrastructure" CI/CD resources<sup>1</sup>.

> Is this point and click in the AWS console or can it be done with CloudFormation?

Yes and Yes.  You can use `sam deploy` (or `aws cloudformation deploy`) to update the stacks.  Or point and click.

Example: update the `serverlessrepo-super-app-toolchain` template with the SAM CLI:

```sh
# compile
sam build -t cicd_template.yaml --region us-east-1 --profile sandbox

# send changes to the cloud
sam deploy --stack-name serverlessrepo-super-app-toolchain --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM --region us-east-1 --profile sandbox
```

You must pass in values for the [template parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) at deploy-time.  The current values for the parameters are in the console under `CloudFormation > Stack > Parameters Tab`. You can pass them using the `--parameter-overrides` param in the `deploy` command.   If the
parameters are static, I find it easier to pass SAM parameter values in [samconfig.toml](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-config.html), which `sam deploy` will use by default:

```
# samconfig.toml
version = 0.1
[default]
[default.deploy]
[default.deploy.parameters]
# template default parameters - fill in the template blanks
# Where do the values come from?  the CloudFormation console, Parameters tab
AppId = "super-app"
AppResourceArns = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:1xxxxxx:function..."
ConnectionArn = "arn:aws:codestar-connections:us-east-1:xxxxxx:connection/xxxx3c5c-f0fe-4eb9-8164-d3c2xxxxx6e2"
GitHubRepositoryOwner = "mygithuborg"
RepositoryName = "super-app"
SourceCodeBucketKey = "sample-apps/nodejs/14.x/javascript/sam/web-backend.zip"
SourceCodeBucketName = "prodiadstack-subsystemsn-apptemplatesbucket03axxx-96eem3xxxxxx"
UseCodeCommit = false
```

If there were changes made in the template, they will deploy.  Success!

### Part 2: In which I try to convince you to use the CDK instead

SAM and YAML templates are far from dead, but I think it's safe to say that for proficient developers starting out with AWS, the newer [AWS Cloud Development Kit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/work-with.html) is a natural first choice for ambitious applications that need CI/CD and testing.  For most of us, editing a 800-line YAML file is not a fun experience.

#### AWS Infrastructure-As-Code

There are lots AWS and 3rd Party IaaC tools to deploy infra on AWS.  Each abstraction is best for somebody sometime.  The important thing to remember is that *no matter what higher-level IaaC toolset you use, it ends up being deployed as a CloudFormation template*.  Here are the AWS approaches, oldest to newest:

##### CloudFormation YAML<sup>2</sup> templates

The OG, all-powerful, lowest-level approach is to hand-code YAML templates.  The [Cfn template reference
docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-reference.html) are indespensible no
matter what tool you use, because that's what gets deployed.

##### SAM YAML templates

With [AWS SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html), you
still handcode YAML, but less<sup>3</sup>.  A [SAM template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification.html) is a superset of CloudFormation with some higher-level abstractions for the main serverless components like Lambdas, DynamoDB tables and Queues.  The [SAM CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-command-reference.html) compiles the SAM template to Cfn.  It has nifty features like local testing and deploy conveniences.

##### Cloud Development Kit

The newest, shiniest IaaC approach is the CDK, [now on V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/home.html).  With the CDK, we write Typescript/Python/Java/etc. instead of YAML.  The [CDK CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cli.html) compiles your language code to Cfn and deploys with `cdk deploy`.  It has a bigger set of [high-level infra abstractions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/constructs.html#constructs_using) that goes beyond serverless, and [escape hatches](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html) to expose low-level Cfn constructs for advanced use cases. It natively supports [testing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/testing.html) and [CI/CD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cdk_pipeline.html).

AWS [CDK workshop](https://cdkworkshop.com) including testing and pipelines.  Lots of AWS [CDK example apps](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/tree/master/typescript).

---

1. Note that CloudFormation is the ultimate soure of this info.  The lambda console makes a `cloudformation.DescribeStack` API call to fetch it.
2. YAML or JSON
3. SAM also has a [marketplace-like repository](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverlessrepo/latest/devguide/what-is-serverlessrepo.html) with reusable AWS and 3rd party components

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Other than by looking at the stack in the AWS console, is the definition of the CI/CD infrastructure anywhere else? Surely doing sam deploy from the repo that has no information about the infrastructure can't deploy the infrastructure, right?

Comment: Glad to help.  You need to copy-paste the `serverlessrepo-super-app-toolchain` stack's template from the AWS console into your repo.  The file name is unimportant, I named it `cicd_template.yaml` in the answer.    Locally, edit that `.yaml` to add Cfn configuration for your new deploy stages.  Then deploy as in the answer.  Once deployed, you will notice the template in the AWS Console will have changed to match the changes you pushed.

Answer (score 0):

Edit :

If I understand correctly, you want to reproduce the deployment on the SAM app. If that's the case, there is an [AWS sample](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-serverless-cicd-workshop) that covers the same approach.

---

It seems you are using either CodeStar/CodeCommit/CodePipeline/CodeDeploy/Code... etc. from AWS to deploy your SAM application on `example1`.

At deploy time, these resources under `infrastructure` are created by the "Code" services family in order to authorize, instantiate, build, validate, store, and deploy your application to CloudFormation.

On the other hand, on `example2`, whenever you build your project in your local machine, both instantiation, build, validation, storage (of the upload-able built artifacts) are leveraged by your own device, hence not needed be provisioned by AWS.

To shortly answer your question: No. Your can't recreate these infrastructure resources on your own. But again, you wouldn't need to do so while deploying outside of AWS' code services.

Comment: So, the project created from AWS SAM template in the console is not possible to reproduce? If I have another project that I want to be like this, I can't make it?

Comment: You don't need to reproduce anything, both projects are **the same**. What you see under "Infrastructure" are tools CodeStar uses to deploy your app from the console, not part of the app itself.

Comment: I know what I'm seeing in infrastructure is not part of the running app, it's the CI/CD, what picks changes from github, builds them, deploys them. The other project, created from `sam init` doesn't have that. The other project doesn't automatically deploy on each `git push`. That's what I'm trying to figure out how to replicate.

Comment: I see. Either way, the answer still apply as to why SAM CLI doesn't create infrastructure resources. The question would still need clarification though, on how both projects were setup and what do you mean by "reproduce" and "another project be like this".

Comment: Do you perhaps want to setup CI/CD to the SAM project?

Comment: Yes, but that's not the only thing. For example, when I created a permission boundary, it didn't show up in Infrastructure. Why not? What's missing? Can the CI/CD pipeline be defined as code? or do I have to go clicking around in AWS? (I noticed the edit, I'll check out that project, but I wanted to answer your question)

Comment: As I understand it, a permission boundary is a property to a resource, and it'll be shown at its details (instead of under infrastructure, regardless of the deployment method or project setup).

About defining CI/CD as code, you can do it by GitHub Actions + AWS SAM CLI as the sample demonstrates, but it would be essentially different from the one created from AWS Lambda Application. To achieve a similar result (not the same as the underlying tools are different), you can try [AWS SAM + CodeDeploy tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/tutorial-lambda-sam.html).

Comment: But it is show on Infrastructure on example1, it's the four entry on the list.